# How to make Steam download game updates immediately?

Tags: steam

My Steam client always waits for an hour+ to start downloading a game update: "Scheduled for 19:35". There is a button to force update though. Auto-updates are turned on for all games.

How can I make Steam download updates immediately without additional interactions?

Steam settings:

[image: Steam settings]

Comment: Hmm, I've never tried looking for it, but I'm really surprised that it isn't an option in the menu you have a screenshot of.  You would think that would be one of the more common download options.

Comment: Weird, mine just starts downloading updates on its own. I can check my settings tonight to see if I have something set differently.

Comment: For some weird reason, Steam always schedules downloads for 3 AM, when my PC is supposed to be turned off. It's been like that for years.

Comment: `19:35` is a value specified somewhere. Maybe its environmental thing (e.g. provider parameter) and steam is *smart* to use it, to optimize downloading. Try to look for something what has it in windows settings and all other related programs/services.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This isn't something that can be turned off (unless you manually do it per-game), and happens for two (main) reasons:

- The game had some form of error occur while downloading, so it's been scheduled for a few minutes time to try again.
- The game's update has just gone live - and steam cannot handle thousands of people all downloading it at the same time, so it staggers the various updates to ensure that *everyone* is able to get a fast and reliable download.

[Official Source](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta/discussions/1/624076851289397987/)

Comment: Except that the result is not "everyone" getting a fast and reliable download, it's "everyone" reliably not getting their download and having to manually trigger it every single time without fail.

Comment: For me it just schedules for 6 am every time and obviously my computer is never on at 6 am.

Comment: My problem is I usually game with friends over weekend, and I am never exactly sure what games they will want to play (or which of my friends are likely to be online). However the updates are nearly always scheduled for Sunday, or Monday or sometime next week. My connection (the fastest residential option offered in my location) isn't fast enough to ask them what they want to play, and then start it downloading - it would take until after we are all asleep. As a result every weekend I have to force the update of all the games I might want to play on Friday morning.

Comment: @TelFiRE Two years late, but still - Steam is preventing a [thundering herd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem). If every client in the world tries to download an update all at once, the servers will become overloaded and download speeds might drop to mere kilobits per second. Everybody will get the update extremely slowly and nobody will be able to play for hours. Meanwhile, right now, those who force the update can download it quickly and get playing almost immediately. Because everyone else in the world is not also downloading it at the same time.

Comment: @TelFiRE Note that I said only those who force the update get to download it quickly. The reason updates get spread out for days and days is because there are a LOT of Steam users. Between all the users who could be downloading updates, and all the games that they could be downloading updates for... you know. It's a lot to handle and there's a reason the delay is so long. I frequently visit my downloads page and find that there are 15-20 pending updates that haven't been downloaded yet. It's extremely annoying, sure, but Steam *does* prioritize games you've played recently.

Comment: (continuing) If it is an incorrect and lazy excuse then please back up your claims. I don't have any reason to believe that this delayed behavior is for any other reason than to prevent a thundering herd. If you think there is another reason then please enlighten me. Also, this conversation should probably go to chat (although stack hasn't given me the option to move it yet)

Comment: @Dev I want my games available to play at night time when I play. This system quite frankly sux. It's just plain awful. Especially the ones I play all the time. So many times I have to trigger a manual update of many GBs and miss my small window of available playtime because this system is junk.

Comment: @Shiv Yes, it is a very awful user experience and I don't like it either. Steam is protecting themselves, though. Nothing much we can do about that.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is you can't, it's a feature.

It's actually that steam only automatically downloads your most recent played games immediately. Other games are set for future update depending on how long ago you last played them. This started happening about 2+ years ago that I could recall. It's designed that way to relieve bandwidth on game updates.

EG: Path of Exile has a major season update each few months. I have it installed but no longer play it (like I guess a lot of people do with a bunch of games). It delivers the update to people who need it first. Mine is normally set to update days, even weeks later.

I do however wish they would add a "Download all now" button. I'm one of those people that clicks things to get rid of the notifications because they don't look neat/clean and I have hundreds of games installed at once, and clicking each update becomes annoying lol.

Comment: Wish that were true. I use Playnite as my launcher to have all my games from various storefronts available and my most played game is Lost Ark on Steam. Every Wednesday when there is a patch involved, I have to tab out of Playnite and go to Steam to manually update (if the attempt to load the game didn't kick off the update which seems to be a toss up week to week).

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, the best workaround I found is to scroll to the bottom of the update list and click "download now" for the bottom update.  You can keep your mouse cursor in the same place and keep clicking "download now" for each update.  Once you have gotten through the list, they will all be queued for immediate download.

I have an old gaming PC that I rarely use so there are always a ton of updates.  This is how I get them to all run immediately.  Hope this helps.  It's not a fix, but I believe it is an effective workaround.

Comment: That's the method I always use. Though, it's still quite annoying I am forced to do that, especially since all the scheduled times aiming at a crazy one, where Steam will be turned off, anyway.