# How does Steam decide when to update my games?

Tags: steam

I have a few game updates automatically scheduled on Steam. What I don't get is *how* Steam decides when to update a game. The scheduled updates range from tonight at 3AM, Wednesday at 2:35 to 8th of July at 1:30. Is there any information as to how Steam prioritizes updates? And if so, is it possible for me to add a global schedule for downloads (let's say, start updates for everything on Thursdays at 3 o'clock)?

I'm aware that there are settings for individual games but just having everything ready to go at a certain time would be really useful. Also, knowing how it prioritizes which game to update first would be good information to have.

Comment: Related: [How to make Steam download game updates immediately?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/330484/4797)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Delayed updates](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371246/143571)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly for now there is no auto-update for each specific day. If you would like to do this then you will do the following:

1. You will have to go to Steam section above STORE and then hover over it. Then you will find the settings and then you will have to edit the auto-update time for (num)AM-(num)AM.
2. Then you will set the time and save the settings, after that You can remove the check mark in the days you don't want to update games in.. You will manually do this.. Also don't worry it will save the update time so the next day you will just go to the same download settings and add the check mark again

Also for prioritizing you will have to go to the library, click that gear icon in the selected game you want to prioritize, and then Choose properties. Then go to updates and choose from dropdown menu: High Priority - Always update this game before others, Choose it and it's done.

Hope this helps!